# How to start a native process with restricted permissions in .net and IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, iis

I have a web application that runs on .NET and IIS, and I need to start a native process. However, this process is not fully trusted, so I need to restrict its access to the system, specifically:

- block all network access
- access to only certain directories in the system (configurable at runtime)

Things I can't use:

- .NET AppDomains (doesn't apply to native executables)
- runas separate user (IIS does not have permissions to run as a different user, and I haven't found any way to grant IIS these permissions)
- UAC on the process (the directory access must be configurable at runtime, and UAC doesn't seem to allow that)

Does anyone know of a way I can achieve this?

Comment: Doesn't Chrome use a sandbox library?

Comment: This is server side, not client side.

Comment: a library is usable anywhere (if it exists which I'm not sure of). Sandboxing is not tied to a GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on exactly what the process does, one option is to have IIS signal the process to run rather than run it directly.

For example, you could create a simple Windows Service that receives a signal from IIS (by writing to a queue, setting a flag in the database, or any of the IPC mechanisms available on Windows) and then manages the lifecycle of the native process (starts it e.g. using Runas, awaits completion, sends the results back to IIS).

If the native process can be converted to a Windows Service, the intermediate "proxy" Windows Service could be avoided.

Comment: That's actually something I've tried too: making a windows service that listens for signals from the web app, and running processes as separate users from there. I've found that the user under which windows services run (the SYSTEM user, IIRC) *also* doesn't have permissions to run as different users, just like the IIS user. :-(

Comment: You *can* configure your windows service to run as any use you like.  If you look in Services, right-click on the "proxy" service, Properties, Log On tab.  Select option This Account (wording may vary slightly by Windows version).  Enter an account that you custom-create to provide the minimal set of permissions needed to accomplish the task.  I suspect that IIS can be configured to run as a different user, but I would not recommend that as it would open new attack vectors for hackers.

Comment: OK, I wasn't aware that you could change the user that windows services run under. I'll have to try that. Thanks!